# ImportError: No module named PIL

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, easy-install

I use this command in the shell to install PIL:

```
easy_install PIL
```

then I run `python` and type this: `import PIL`. But I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named PIL
```

I've never had such problem, what do you think?

Comment: @RikPoggi [This page of documentation](http://www.pythonware.com/library/pil/handbook/image.htm) actually tells to use `from PIL import Image`, which does not work.

Comment: @Janne just use Import Image,and PIL starts working.

Comment: At this time I'd recommend to `easy_install Pillow` instead. Pillow is a fork of PIL that has better packaging and supports Python 3.

Comment: Can you change the accepted answer to one that recommends Pillow? As @LennartRegebro said, this package is better long-term.

Comment: Use `pip install Pillow` instead. Then you can do `import PIL.Image`

Answer (score 184, accepted):

On some installs of PIL, you must do

```
import Image
```

instead of `import PIL` (PIL is in fact not always imported this way).  Since `import Image` works for you, this means that you have in fact installed PIL.

Having a different name for the library and the Python module is unusual, but this is what was chosen for (some versions of) PIL.

You can get more information about how to use this module from the [official tutorial](http://effbot.org/imagingbook/introduction.htm).

**PS**: In fact, on *some* installs, `import PIL` *does* work, which adds to the confusion. This is confirmed by an [example from the documentation](http://effbot.org/imagingbook/image.htm), as @JanneKarila found out, and also by some more recent versions of the MacPorts PIL package (1.1.7).

Comment: `pip install image` from Zhiming's answer worked for me.

Comment: yup, @JimSchubert said it. `pip install image` from `@zhimmingwang` worked for me too

Comment: But `image` is _not_ PIL (as in the question), it's a different module. Reference: https://github.com/francescortiz/image. Am I missing something, here?

Comment: I got the same error "ImportError: No module named PIL". Installed Pillow with "pip install Pillow" and tried to run the script. Still got the same error. Then, I tried to import an image, it says 'No module named image' found. I installed image using 'pip install image' and tried again. No luck. Any suggestions?

Comment: You should check that your `pip` installs for the python interpreter that you are using. `pip -V` tells you where it installs. Under Unix, `which python` tells you where your `python` command is. The two should match well enough. Or, better: `python -c 'import sys; print sys.path'` will tell you where your `python` command looks for modules (`print(sys.path)`, for Python 3).

Comment: When I installed Pillow with conda, `import PIL` works. Not sure if that's an exception or the rule

Comment: This is the official way of importing Pillow, which is a more modern fork (https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/handbook/tutorial.html). Note that the `import Image`of this answer thus seems to be `from PIL import Image`, with Pillow.

Comment: @EricOLebigot Yours is a seemingly underappreciated solution, your suggestion resolved my issue perfectly, and prevented me from downloading any other packages

Comment: This Should be `import image` (note the lowercase "i") - after all you are running `pip install image` also with a lowercase i

Comment: `pip3 install image`
 in my case, look for your python version. `python -V`

Comment: no module named Image

Comment: Again, this works on _some_ installs. Try `import PIL`.

Answer (score 510):

In shell, run:

```
pip install Pillow
```

Attention: PIL is deprecated, and [pillow](https://pypi.org/project/pillow/) is the successor.

Comment: Really? `image` is _not_ the PIL module of the question, it's instead a "Django application" (that happens to be _based_ on PIL). Reference: https://github.com/francescortiz/image.

Comment: `pip install image` worked for me. thanks to duckduckgo cache for holding onto pre-edit answer!

Comment: I've seen PILLOW other places, Pillow here.  `cmd` is not case-sensitive, but what is the preferred way of writing this?

Comment: installing image with that weird django thing got this script i found to run at least.  It didn't get far enough to test the package though.

Comment: When I key "pip install Pillow" in Terminal, it appears this error:
Requirement already satisfied: Pillow in c:\users\user\venv\odoo\lib\site-packages (6.2.2)

Comment: DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 reached the end of its life on
 January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Pyth
on 2.7 is no longer maintained. pip 21.0 will drop sup
port for Python 2.7 in January 2021. More details abou
t Python 2 support in pip, can be found at https://pip
.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python
-2-support

Answer (score 72):

On a different note, I can highly recommend the use of [Pillow](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pillow) which is backwards compatible with PIL and is better maintained/will work on newer systems.

When that is installed you can do

```
import PIL
```

or

```
from PIL import Image
```

etc..

Comment: None of the other answers fixed the issue I had, but this one did.

Comment: The second one no longer works.
https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/installation.html

Answer (score 71):

At first install Pillow with

```
pip install Pillow
```

or as follows

```
c:\Python35>python -m pip install Pillow
```

Then in python code you may call

```
from PIL import Image
```

"Pillow is a fork of PIL, the Python Imaging Library, which is no longer maintained. However, to maintain backwards compatibility, the old module name is used." From [pillow installed, but "no module named pillow" - python2.7 - Windows 7 - python -m install pillow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23834663/pillow-installed-but-no-module-named-pillow-python2-7-windows-7-python)

Comment: i am getting Requirement already satisfied  but still the same issue

Answer (score 27):

Sometimes I get this type of error running a Unitest in python. The solution is  to uninstall and install the same package  on your  virtual environment.

Using this commands:

```
pip uninstall PIL
```

and

```
pip install  PIL
```

If for any reason  you get an error, add  sudo at the beginning of the command  and after hitting enter  type your password.

Comment: This also works for me. Consider that one might use other Python scripts that indirectly uses PIL, changing the Import statement is not always an option.

Comment: This didn't work for me, it couldn't find a repository called PIL (or pil). However I ran "pip install Pillow" which did work. My understanding is that Pillow is a branch of PIL.

Comment: @TeeBasins Pillow is the “friendly PIL fork” by Alex Clark and Contributors.

Comment: I get "  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement PIL (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for PIL"

Comment: This worked for me but after I updated the pip installer.... To update, run: python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip  ---> pip uninstall Pillow ----> pip install Pillow

Answer (score 26):

This worked for me on Ubuntu 16.04:

```
sudo apt-get install python-imaging
```

I found this on [Wikibooks](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Python_Imaging_Library/Getting_PIL) after searching for about half an hour.

Comment: This question was asked before the Ubuntu 16.04, but I met this problem in Ubunt 16.04 and fixed it with your suggestion.

Comment: Glad I could help! :D

Comment: This was my issue on a RPI with an OLED screen displaying python output

Comment: This fixed my issue with Pillow but my actual problem was that python 2 was used when I typed `python` in the command line instead of python3 (you can check for this with `python -V`)

Answer (score 17):

you have to install Image and pillow with your python package.

type

```
python -m pip install image
```

or run command prompt (in windows), then navigate to the scripts folder

```
cd C:\Python27\Scripts
```

then run below command

```
pip install image
```

Comment: For python3 use

`python3 -m pip install Pillow`

Comment: Uninstalling Pillow and then installing image worked for me.

Answer (score 15):

I used:

```
pip install Pillow
```

and pip installed PIL in Lib\site-packages. When I moved PIL to Lib everything worked fine. I'm on Windows 10.

Answer (score 15):

On windows 10 I managed to get there with:

```
cd "C:\Users\<your username>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32" 
python -m pip install --upgrade pip     <-- upgrading from 10.something to 19.2.2.
pip3 uninstall pillow
pip3 uninstall PIL
pip3 install image
```

after which in python (python 3.7 in my case) this works fine...

```
import PIL
from PIL import image
```

Comment: After upgrading windows 7 to windows 10 my python program didn't work but this method solved it. Thanks!

Answer (score 13):

Install Specific Version:

```
pip install Pillow
```

Upgrade  Pillow

```
sudo pip3 install --upgrade Pillow
```

Getting Dependency Error in Window 10
Use code: easy_install instead of pip install

```
easy_install Pillow
```

Upgrade using easy install

```
sudo easy_install --upgrade  Pillow
```

On OSX System to install Module:
Use code: brew install instead of pip install

```
brew install Pillow
```

Without Using Pip :

```
 sudo apt-get install -y Pillow
```

On CentOS7 or Linux Fedora:

```
yum -y install Pillow
```

Or on Fedora try

```
sudo dnf install Pillow
```

Command if Homebrew screws up your path on macOS:

```
python -m pip install Pillow
```

For Python3 MacOs Homebrew screws

```
python3 -m pip install Pillow
```

Verify module from list MacOs

```
pip freeze | grep  Pillow
```

For Execute on Anaconda as your python package manager

```
 conda install -c anaconda Pillow
```

Comment: upgrading the Pillow did it for me on windows11

Answer (score 9):

On windows, try checking the path to the location of the PIL library.  On my system, I noticed the path was

```
\Python26\Lib\site-packages\pil instead of \Python26\Lib\site-packages\PIL
```

after  renaming the `pil` folder to `PIL`, I was able to load the PIL module.

Comment: I was also getting same import error. I have installed PIL using easy_install. In site-packages it was installed in directory with 'PIL-1.1.7-py2.7-win32.egg' name. As per your suggestion i have changed the dir name to PIL and it worked. Thanks for your help @Komla.

Answer (score 8):

if you use anaconda:

```
conda install pillow
```

Comment: I did this, it still couldnt import PIL

Comment: @johnktejik which version of Python and Anaconda are you using?

Answer (score 8):

The cleanest way to resolve this issue is by following below steps.

**Step 1:** Uninstall the PIL package.

```
pip uninstall PIL
```

**Step 2:** Install the Pillow using pip as shown below on windows operating systems. For other environments checkout the article [No module named PIL](https://itsmycode.com/python-importerror-no-module-named-pil-solution/)

On Windows

```
python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip
python3 -m pip install --upgrade Pillow
```

**Step 3:** The most crucial class in the [Python Imaging Library](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image) is the Image class, and you can import this as shown below.

```
from PIL import Image
im = Image.open("myimage.jpg")
```

If successful, this function returns an Image object. You can now use instance attributes to examine the file contents:

```
print(im.format, im.size, im.mode)

#Output: PPM (512, 512) RGB
```

Comment: This has worked for me on windows 11.

Comment: This worked for me on macOS Monterey, after every other face_recognition/dlib install python fix failed.  I needed to downgrade to py 3.9 from 3.11 tho.

Answer (score 7):

I had the same issue on windows 10 and this worked for me:

> pip install Pillow

Answer (score 6):

You will need to install Image and pillow with your python package. 
Rest assured, the command line will take care of everything for you.

Hit

**python -m pip install image**

Answer (score 6):

instead of **PIL** use **Pillow** it works

```
easy_install Pillow
```

or

```
pip install Pillow
```

Answer (score 5):

```
pip(3) uninstall Pillow
pip(3) uninstall PIL
pip(3) install Pillow
```

Answer (score 5):

This worked for me on `Ubuntu 20.04`:

```
pip install image
```

And in script:

```
import image
```

Answer (score 2):

use **pil** instead of **PIL**

```
from pil import Image
```

Answer (score 2):

I found an easier solution. Use a virtual environment.

```
pip install Pillow
```

```
from PIL import Image
```

This works for me on a macOS

Answer (score 1):

On  Windows, you need to download it and install the .exe

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pillow/2.7.0

Answer (score 1):

I used conda-forge to install pillow version 5, and that seemed to work for me:

```
conda install --channel conda-forge pillow=5
```

the normal conda install pillow did NOT work for me.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and i fixed it by checking what version pip (`pip3 --version`) is, then realizing I'm typing `python<uncorrect version> filename.py` instead of `python<correct version> filename.py`

Answer (score 1):

I used :

```
from pil import Image
```

instead of

```
from PIL import Image
```

and it worked for me fine

wish you bests

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue while importing PIL and further importing the ImageTk and Image modules. I also tried installing PIL directly through pip. but not success could be achieved. As in between it has been suggested that PIL has been deprectaed, thus, tried to install pillow through pip only. pillow was successfully installed, further, the PIL package was made under the path : python27/Lib/site-packages/.

Now both Image and ImageTk could be imported.

Answer (score 0):

I recently installed Leap. I Tried openshot and it didn't start. So came here and found a suggestion to start from the Terminal to see if there were any error.

The error I had was `error missing mlt`. So I installed the `python-mlt` module from Yast and imported it, tried to start but next openshot said `missing pil.`

I Followed the Pillow suggestion to install because Yast couldn't find any pil and imported pil. That went ok but did not start and showed `Error missing goocanvas`.

The I installed `goocanvas` with Yast, imported it in python, and Openshot fired up !!

With a lot of errors in the terminal like `missing Vimeoclient` and lots of `attributeerrors`. Well, will see if it is of any influence working with it.

Answer (score 0):

Python 3.8 on Windows 10.   A combination of the answers worked for me. See below for a standalone working example. The commented out lines should be executed in the command line.

```
import requests
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# pip uninstall pillow
# pip uninstall PIL
# pip install image
from PIL import Image
url = "https://images.homedepot-static.com/productImages/007164ea-d47e-4f66-8d8c-fd9f621984a2/svn/architectural-mailboxes-house-letters-numbers-3585b-5-64_1000.jpg"
response = requests.get(url, stream=True)
img = Image.open(response.raw)
plt.imshow(img)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and tried many of the solutions listed above.

I then remembered that I have multiple versions of Python installed AND I use the PyCharm IDE (which is where I was getting this error message), **so the solution in my case was**:

In PyCharm:

go to File>Settings>Project>Python Interpreter

click "+" (install)

locate Pillow from the list and install it

Hope this helps anyone who may be in a similar situation!

Answer (score 0):

According to the official website[Install Pillow](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/installation.html), you may want to try this:

go to Terminal and run:

- `python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip`

Then Run on

- `source ~/.bash_profile`

Answer (score 0):

I installed Pillow through my terminal which used Python 3.11. My IDE (PyCharm) was set to Python 3.12 as an interpreter. I changed that and it worked.

Answer (score -13):

You are probably missing the python headers to build pil. If you're using ubuntu or the likes it'll be something like

```
apt-get install python-dev
```

Comment: What architecture are you using, if 64bit you're in for a world of hurt. Use a 32 bit version and use the unofficial precompiled version from [here](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/image-sig/2009-September/005872.html)

Comment: It's 32 bit,I've installed this for several times,but this this time I have this problem