# Pillow installed, but getting "no module named pillow" when importing

Tags: python, pip, python-imaging-library, python-import

I installed the `Pillow` package with:

```
python -m pip install pillow
```

Got success message (`Successfully installed pillow`).  Closed and re-opened the terminal.

But when I try to:

```
import pillow
```

I get the error message:

> ImportError: No module named pillow

If `python -m pip install pillow` is run again, it says

```
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pillow in c:\python27\lib\site-packages
```

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Try using

```
import PIL
```

or

```
from PIL import ...
```

instead. [`Pillow`](http://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) is a fork of [`PIL`](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/), the Python Imaging Library, which is no longer maintained. However, to maintain backwards compatibility, the old module name is used.

Comment: no module named PIL

Comment: @user7082181 did you successfully run `pip install pillow` and are you using the same interpreter used to install it?