# ImportError: no module named Image, ImportError: no module named PIL -- Python, Anaconda, PIL, pillow, mac 10.10.3,

Tags: macos, python-2.7, anaconda, python-imaging-library

I'm using a Mac OS x 10.10.3 Yosemite, and Python 2.7.9 |Anaconda 2.2.0 (x86_64) for a lot of python stuff. I'm using eclipse, and google app engine.

I'm running out of stack overflow posts to read for this error that a lot of people have, then resolve by some means that has not work for me.

I'm getting this error:

import Image
    ImportError: No module named Image

**From this code:**

```
try:
    from PIL import Image
except:
    import Image
```

After I already tried the following:

```
conda install pillow
sudo pip install pillow
pip install pillow
pip install pil
```

Some stack overflow post suggested seeing if the path was there for another user, so I tried this in my terminal:

```
python
Python 2.7.9 |Anaconda 2.2.0 (x86_64)| (default, Dec 15 2014, 10:37:34) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5577)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Anaconda is brought to you by Continuum Analytics.
Please check out: http://continuum.io/thanks and https://binstar.org
>>> import sys
>>> print(sys.path)
```

**and got:**

```
['', 
'/Users/jrussek/anaconda/lib/python27.zip',
'/Users/jrussek/anaconda/lib/python2.7',
'/Users/jrussek/anaconda/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin', 
'/Users/jrussek/anaconda/lib/python2.7/plat-mac', 
'/Users/jrussek/anaconda/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages',
'/Users/jrussek/anaconda/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
'/Users/jrussek/anaconda/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
'/Users/jrussek/anaconda/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
'/Users/jrussek/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
'/Users/jrussek/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Sphinx-1.2.3 py2.7.egg', 
'/Users/jrussek/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/aeosa', 
'/Users/jrussek/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cryptography-0.8-py2.7-macosx-10.5-x86_64.egg', 
'/Users/jrussek/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-14.3-py2.7.egg']
```

I thought it wasn't in my path so I tried to append the thing:

```
 PYTHONPATH=/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PIL
```

didn't look like it showed up.

So I tried uninstalling, and reinstalling, in 10 different ways. I only did that for pillow, not PIL because I tried different things for PIL and looked at a lot of posts that said use pillow, not PIL because PIL is deprecated.

Anyway, for pillow I keep getting:

```
Requirement already up-to-date: pillow in ./anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

clearly pillow is already installed in anaconda, but that doesn't help the import error I keep getting.

so then I tried conda install pillow,

and it upgraded some stuff:

but.. I try running my code again, and I still get no module found, no matter what import statement I try.

Suggestions? Please? Anyone?

Comment: I am using a similar stack, although I am currently using Python 3.4. Anaconda works for me. What does it say for you when you type `conda search pil`?

Comment: It says: `Fetching package metadata: ....
pil                          1.1.7                    py27_0  defaults        
                              blah blah        
                          *  2.8.2                    py27_0  defaults        
                             2.8.2                    py26_0  defaults  `

Comment: I am having the same problem with python 3.4.3 - anaconda distribution.

Answer (score 12):

The following does work for me:

```
from PIL import Image
```

And this does not work:

```
import Image
```

**Pillow package**

```
$ conda search pillow
Fetching package metadata: ....
pillow                       2.1.0                    py33_0  defaults        
                             2.1.0                    py27_0  defaults        
                             2.1.0                    py26_0  defaults        
                             2.3.1                    py34_0  defaults        
                             2.3.1                    py33_0  defaults        
                             2.3.1                    py27_0  defaults        
                             2.3.1                    py26_0  defaults        
                             2.4.0                    py34_0  defaults        
                             2.4.0                    py33_0  defaults        
                             2.4.0                    py27_0  defaults        
                             2.4.0                    py26_0  defaults        
                          .  2.5.1                    py34_0  defaults        
                             2.5.1                    py33_0  defaults        
                             2.5.1                    py27_0  defaults        
                             2.5.1                    py26_0  defaults        
                             2.7.0                    py34_0  defaults        
                             2.7.0                    py33_0  defaults        
                             2.7.0                    py27_0  defaults        
                             2.7.0                    py26_0  defaults        
                             2.7.0                    py34_1  defaults        
                             2.7.0                    py33_1  defaults        
                             2.7.0                    py27_1  defaults        
                             2.7.0                    py26_1  defaults        
                             2.8.1                    py34_1  defaults        
                             2.8.1                    py33_1  defaults        
                             2.8.1                    py27_1  defaults        
                             2.8.1                    py26_1  defaults        
                             2.8.1                    py34_2  defaults        
                             2.8.1                    py33_2  defaults        
                             2.8.1                    py27_2  defaults        
                             2.8.1                    py26_2  defaults        
                             2.8.2                    py34_0  defaults        
                             2.8.2                    py33_0  defaults        
                             2.8.2                    py27_0  defaults        
                             2.8.2                    py26_0  defaults        
                          *  2.9.0                    py34_0  defaults        
                             2.9.0                    py33_0  defaults        
                             2.9.0                    py27_0  defaults        
                             2.9.0                    py26_0  defaults
```

**Python path**

```
$ python
Python 3.4.3 |Anaconda 2.1.0 (x86_64)| (default, Mar  6 2015, 12:07:41) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5577)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> print (sys.path)
['', '/Users/erwin/anaconda/lib/python34.zip', '/Users/erwin/anaconda/lib/python3.4', '/Users/erwin/anaconda/lib/python3.4/plat-darwin', '/Users/erwin/anaconda/lib/python3.4/lib-dynload', '/Users/erwin/anaconda/lib/python3.4/site-packages', '/Users/erwin/anaconda/lib/python3.4/site-packages/Sphinx-1.3.1-py3.4.egg', '/Users/erwin/anaconda/lib/python3.4/site-packages/setuptools-18.1-py3.4.egg']
```

**Image usage**

This works both in my terminal and in Eclipse PyDev now.

```
>>> from PIL import Image
>>> a = Image.new("RGB", (512,512), "red")
>>> a.show()
```

Comment: :) notice in the post: I'm getting this error:

import Image ImportError: No module named Image

From this code:

try:
    from PIL import Image
except:
    import Image                       --so I would think that code should try what works for you already... any more suggestions?

Comment: I don't have any more suggestions, but I can show you what I see in a working configuration. I add it to the post.

Answer (score 6):

At first, try installing Pillow with (Capital letter P)

```
pip install Pillow
```

then use 
    from PIL import Image
"Pillow is a fork of PIL, the Python Imaging Library, which is no longer maintained. However, to maintain backwards compatibility, the old module name is used." From: [pillow installed, but "no module named pillow" - python2.7 - Windows 7 - python -m install pillow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23834663/pillow-installed-but-no-module-named-pillow-python2-7-windows-7-python)

Comment: also, I never tried the --upgrade option on the install, which might have been the issue the entire time. (untested theory)

Comment: Saved my a. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for posting this! For others having trouble with `from scipy.misc import imread`, uninstalling `pillow` and installing `Pillow` fixed my issue.

Answer (score 4):

Newer version of Pillow has been changed decleration of "image" as:

```
from PIL.Image import core as image
```

Answer (score 0):

I've been in the same position as you at least a few times, and I somehow managed to resolve it through other solutions. Then it broke again. Here is what I did that fixed it:

Open two finder windows.

In one, navigate to:

```
//anaconda/pkgs/pillow-3.2.0-py27_0/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

In this folder, you will find the folder

```
PIL
```

Copy this folder and paste it somewhere accessible.

Now open your python 2.7 environment folder within the anaconda directory. For me, it's:

```
//anaconda/envs/py27/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

You should only have to change the "py27" in that.

Even if there is already a folder in there named "PIL", put your copied PIL in the new site-packages folder. From what I can tell, the existing PIL folder in there is old or wrong, or something. Or pillow doesn't install it correctly. I think this amounts to a manual installation of a python module. Super fun.

Answer (score 0):

I was running into the same problem as OP:

- macOS 10.12.5
- Python 2.7.13 [GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 8.1.0 (clang-802.0.38)] on darwin

The problem ended up being the the **.py** file I was trying to run.

At the top of the script there was a [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)): `#!/usr/bin/python`

*However*, my default python does not run from the system installation. I used `homebrew` to upgrade python, so my default path is:

```
$ which python
/usr/local/bin/python
```

I changed the shebang at the top to `#!/usr/local/bin/python`, and after that I was able to run my script (which was calling `from PIL import Image`).