# ImportError: No module named PIL python 2.7.10

Tags: python, macos, python-imaging-library, macos-mojave

I am not able to import `PIL` on macOS, it works fine on windows with python version 2.7.16.

Any help for python 2.7.10 would be much appreciated.

```
from PIL import Image
```

**ERROR:-**

```
ImportError: No module named PIL
```

I am getting this error with python (2.7.10) pip(19.1.1) on macos Mojave (10.14.4)

pip list outputs pillow in the packages version (5.2.0)

```
pip install pillow
```

Logs the following:

```
Requirement already satisfied: pillow in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages (5.2.0)
```

But i am still unable to import the package.
Any workarounds for this?

Comment: It should work. Have you check rights on the site-package directory?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ImportError: no module named Image, ImportError: no module named PIL -- Python, Anaconda, PIL, pillow, mac 10.10.3,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31016085/importerror-no-module-named-image-importerror-no-module-named-pil-python)