# cannot import Image from PIL in Python 3.8

Tags: python, macos, image, pycharm, python-imaging-library

I am using macOS and installed pillow in the terminal with code `pip3 install pillow` and I got the version 8.0.1.

But I cannot import it in Pycharm. I typed `from PIL import Image` and an error message show `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PIL'` . then I changed PIL to pillow `from pillow import Image`, it works but cannot find Image class.

How can I fix it?

Comment: Try `path/your/favourite/python -m pip install pillow`.

Comment: When you get it installed properly, `from PIL import Image` is the right way to do it.

Comment: did I install python3 on the right path? I typed `which python3` in the terminal and it turns `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3`

Comment: You have to make sure that Pycharm is using the same Python env where you installed Pillow (meaning it should use the same `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/..`)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PyCharm doesn't recognise installed module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31235376/pycharm-doesnt-recognise-installed-module)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is very likely that your Pycharm has created a virtual environment for the project and is not using the same library as the python on the system.

If that is the case, go to Settings > Project > Python Interpreter, press on the plus sign (+), write Pillow on the search bar, select the right package, and add it to your interpreter running on PyCharm.

I recommend the use of the pipenv tool to manage your project dependencies for each project. It helps you to maintain the project dependencies separated from the system or other projects.

Answer (score 0):

`Pillow` not `pillow`.

run `pip uninstall pillow` then run `pip install Pillow`.

Comment: [It is case-insensitive](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26503509/2745495). Installing `pillow` or `Pillow` is the same. The problem is with the OP's Pycharm env.

Comment: @GinoMempin its not only me who says this, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35395516/11132419). i checked the question you've posted before answering so i don't answer a wrong answer, but then i found out it is case sensitive in this case.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if the solutions given have worked for everyone but try but writing the imports out separately. I tried everything and by accident this worked. So try as below, I hope this works for anyone who needs the help

```
from PIL import Image

from PIL import ImageTk
```

Comment: `from PIL import Image` was already mentioned in the question and is the line that's giving the problem. Why do you think this would solve anything? Since you wrote "by accident this worked", I guess you had a different (unrelated) problem at the time.