# Getting "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Pillow'" in VS Code

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code, python-imaging-library

I installed the Pillow module within a virtual env as such:

```
(venv)$python -m pip install --upgrade Pillow 
Collecting Pillow
  Downloading Pillow-7.2.0-cp38-cp38-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (2.2 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 2.2 MB 2.4 MB/s 
Installing collected packages: Pillow
Successfully installed Pillow-7.2.0
```

The VS Code interpreter is the same as the terminal version:

[image]

```
$python --version
Python 3.8.0
$ which python
/mnt/d/github/python_dev/venv/bin/python
```

But when I run `from Pillow import Image` I still got `ModuleNotFoundError`:

```
$ ../venv/bin/python images.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "images.py", line 1, in <module>
    from PIL import Image
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Pillow'
```

I knew there are many posts regarding this topic but I'm still stuck here for almost half a day.  What's the best way to fix it?

Comment: did you activate environment first?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pillow installed, but getting "no module named pillow" when importing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23834663/pillow-installed-but-getting-no-module-named-pillow-when-importing)

Comment: Yes.  By source venv/bin/activate

Comment: @GinoMempin, Tried the link but it does not work for me.

Comment: Just to be clear here, your venv name is also `"venv"`? (based on the VS Code image). Also, why are you specifying what seems to be the full path to python from the venv? (`../venv/bin/python`) If the venv is activated, just `python` should work.

Comment: It's also not clear from the console logs you posted if the venv is actually activated. Normally, it should show `(venv)` at the start of the prompt, [even in VS Code's Terminal panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MNshf.png).

Comment: it does have `(venv) bridlebit@Zhang_family-PC:/mnt/d/github/python_dev/sec17_scripting$ `

Answer (score 0):

There is no command like:-

```
from Pillow import Image
```

Python likes to import Pillow module as PIL.

So, Try to use:-

```
from PIL import Image
```

It Worked for me. :)

Comment: I still got error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PIL'`

Comment: Do you able import other modles like json, sqlite3, etc. If not, try to reinstall the python interpreter, because it should work with "import PIL".

Comment: I can import json

Comment: Try to go to the python directory in which all the python modules are installed and try to find directory named "PIL". If its not there then remove and reinstall package with pip. Hope it Works!

Comment: try to go to /mnt/d/github/python_dev/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages@DavidZ

Answer (score 0):

There is no magic. Every time this happens you can debug it by yourself:

```
(venv) etoneja@ois ~/Projects/***/venv/lib (master)$ grep -r -w "class Image"
python3.8/site-packages/PIL/Image.py:class Image:
```

and

```
(venv) etoneja@ois ~/Projects/***/venv/lib (master)$ find . -iname "Pil"
./python3.8/site-packages/PIL
```

Also check this output

```
(venv) etoneja@ois ~/Projects/***/venv/lib (master)$ pip list
Package       Version
------------- --------
Pillow        7.1.2
```

If there is no Pillow, so somethings wrong with your installation.
Check that you activate the current venv.

So the answer:

```
from PIL import Image
```

Comment: Thanks! I can find these packages by either grep or find but still same error

Comment: Try to open shell by printing `python` while venv activated and execute `import` from it. Does it works?

Comment: Also try reload vscode or disable some plugins for test, if Pillow is in `pip list` output.

Comment: I can run `$python images.py` in terminal but not through vs code..so weird..

Comment: Open python shell first, later in vs code and try this ```import sys, print(sys.path)```. Is path to `site-packages` there?

Comment: there are four paths: `['', '/usr/lib/python38.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.8', '/usr/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload', '/mnt/d/github/python_dev/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages']`

Comment: These is a WSL badge on your screenshot - maybe some mess with its paths. U have to understand which interpretator you run at each moment and which paths it looking for. Maybe read about how python packages work. Without seeing your real setup pretty difficult to understand what is wrong. Base debug logic was provided.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have 2 problems:

1. From your original problem, there is no `from Pillow import Image`.

   - As described in [Pillow](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html)'s docs, it is supposed to be a fork of the old `PIL` module
   - As shown in Pillow's [Tutorial](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/handbook/tutorial.html#tutorial) docs, the correct import is same as `PIL`'s:

     ```py
     >>> from PIL import Image
     >>> im = Image.open("hopper.ppm")
     ```
2. From the comments and your responses, either Pillow was not installed correctly in your virtual environment, or your virtual environment is not activated properly.

Seeing your question is for VS Code, here is a step-by-step way to solve problem #2.

1. In VS Code, open a Terminal and create your venv

   ```sh
   cerberus@test$ python3.8 -V
   Python 3.8.5
   cerberus@test$ python3.8 -m venv ~/.venvs/venv
   ```

   - Here, I'm creating the venv in `~/.venvs` with name `venv` ([same as yours](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WyAfh.png) and using Python 3.8 (you can store your venv directory wherever you like)
   - Test that it can be activated correctly and is using correct Python version

   ```sh
   cerberus@test$ source ~/.venvs/venv/bin/activate
   (venv) cerberus@test$ python -V
   Python 3.8.5
   ```

   - You'll know it's activated when your prompt is prefixed with `(venv-name)`
2. **Reload VS Code**

   - When creating new virtual envs, I find it's best to reload VS Code before it can "see" it
   - You could also create the venv outside VS Code, then just open VS Code after
3. After reload, open the command palette and do [`Python: Select Interpreter`](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_select-and-activate-an-environment)
4. Find your created venv from the list
   [image]
5. Close and reopen the Terminal

   - VS Code should auto-activate your chosen venv when it reopens a Terminal
     [image]
   - You could also manually activate the venv

     ```
     cerberus@test$ source ~/.venvs/venv/bin/activate
     (venv) cerberus@test$
     ```
6. Once you've got VS Code to use and activate the correct venv, install Pillow

   ```
   (venv) cerberus@test$ python -V
   Python 3.8.5
   (venv) cerberus@test$ python -m pip install Pillow
   Collecting Pillow
     Using cached Pillow-7.2.0-cp38-cp38-macosx_10_10_x86_64.whl (2.2 MB)
   Installing collected packages: Pillow
   Successfully installed Pillow-7.2.0
   ```
7. Test the installation

   ```
   (venv) cerberus@test$ python
   Python 3.8.5 (default, Jul 21 2020, 10:48:26) 
   [Clang 11.0.3 (clang-1103.0.32.62)] on darwin
   Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
   >>> from PIL import Image
   >>>
   >>> import PIL
   >>> PIL.__path__
   ['/Users/cerberus/.venvs/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PIL']
   ```
8. Now your scripts should work
   [image]

   - As I mentioned in the comments, once you've got your venv activated, there is no need to specify the full path to the `python` interpreter. Just `python` should be fine.

Comment: I did every thing same from #1-#7 and all works but #8