# Using Pillow in Docker

Tags: docker, python-imaging-library

I am not able to install python's PIL module in docker for some reason. Here's a description of what I have:

**requirements.txt**

```
Pillow
flask
redis
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM python:2.7
ADD . /code
WORKDIR /code
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
CMD python app.py
```

**app.py**

```
import PIL
```

**Commands**

```
$ sudo docker build -t web .
Installing collected packages: Pillow, Werkzeug, MarkupSafe, Jinja2, itsdangerous, flask, redis
Successfully installed Jinja2-2.8 MarkupSafe-0.23 Pillow-2.9.0  Werkzeug-0.10.4 flask-0.10.1 itsdangerous-0.24 redis-2.10.3
---> 91dfb38bd480
Removing intermediate container 4e4ca5801814
Step 4 : CMD python app.py
 ---> Running in e71453f2fab6
 ---> d62996658bd6
 Removing intermediate container e71453f2fab6
 Successfully built d62996658bd6

$ sudo docker-compose up
```

Here's what I get:
**Output**

```
web_1   |   File "app.py", line 1, in <module>
web_1   |     import PIL
web_1   | ImportError: No module named PIL
```

I thought maybe adding **PIL** in requirements.txt would work, but here's what happens when I build

```
$ sudo docker build -t web .
....
Collecting PIL (from -r requirements.txt (line 1))
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement PIL (from -r    requirements.txt (line 1)) (from versions: )
Some externally hosted files were ignored as access to them may be  unreliable (use --allow-external PIL to allow).
No matching distribution found for PIL (from -r requirements.txt (line 1))
```

Any idea what should be done from here?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

PIL would be the [Python Imaging Library (PIL)](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/)
(sometimes, [you would need `import Image` instead of `import PIL`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8864020/6309))

According to "[How do I install python imaging library (PIL)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/156484/how-do-i-install-python-imaging-library-pil)", you would need to install others components as well

```
sudo apt-get build-dep python-imaging
sudo apt-get install libjpeg62 libjpeg62-dev
pip install PIL
```

See also [`a5huynh/scrapyd-playground/Dockerfile`](https://github.com/a5huynh/scrapyd-playground/blob/master/Dockerfile) for an example using Pillow (Python Imaging Library) dependencies.

(But be aware, as [Hugo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/724176/hugo) [comments below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32802682/using-pillow-in-docker/32805373?noredirect=1#comment53481210_32805373), that this mixes two modules: PIL and Pillow.
Pillow is a maintained fork and a drop-in replacement of the original, unmaintained PIL, so you shouldn't have both installed at the same time)

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
        python-dev python-pip python-setuptools \
        libffi-dev libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev \
        libtiff4-dev libjpeg8-dev zlib1g-dev libfreetype6-dev \
        liblcms2-dev libwebp-dev tcl8.5-dev tk8.5-dev python-tk
# Add the dependencies to the container and install the python dependencies
ADD requirements.txt /tmp/requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r /tmp/requirements.txt && rm /tmp/requirements.txt
RUN pip install Pillow
```

with requirements:

```
Pillow==2.6.1
Scrapy==0.24.4
Twisted==14.0.2
boto==2.36.0
cffi==0.8.6
characteristic==14.2.0
cryptography==0.6.1
cssselect==0.9.1
lxml==3.4.0
pyOpenSSL==0.14
pyasn1==0.1.7
pyasn1-modules==0.0.5
pycparser==2.10
pymongo==2.8
queuelib==1.2.2
scrapy-mongodb==0.8.0
scrapyd==1.0.1
service-identity==14.0.0
six==1.8.0
w3lib==1.10.0
zope.interface==4.1.1
```

---

In 2019 (4 years later), [Daniel W.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1948292/daniel-w) complains that:

> the decoders / image processors are still missing which results in error like `OSError: decoder tiff_lzw not available`

He adds however:

> I found out my problem originated from a [buggy Pillow version (5.0)](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues/3905), it complained about missing `tiff` stuff but in fact it was not missing.

Comment: Perfect! Used the configs from a5huynh/scrapyd-playground/Dockerfile. But it worked on a fresh container, not the existing one. Don't know why.

Comment: A word of warning, this mixes two modules: `PIL` and `Pillow`. Pillow is a maintained fork and a drop-in replacement of the original, unmaintained PIL, so you shouldn't have both installed at the same time.

Comment: @Hugo Good point: I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: Not helpful in 2019 with `python:3.6.8-slim-jessie`. Everything that is already in the python image (like python itself) is getting reinstalled from Debian repositories but the decoders / image processors are still missing which results in error like `OSError: decoder tiff_lzw not available`.

Comment: @DanielW. OK. What is missing? What could I add (4 years later) that would improve that answer?

Comment: @VonC I found out my problem originated from a [buggy Pillow version (5.0)](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues/3905), it complained about missing tiff stuff but in fact it was not missing.

Comment: @DanielW. Well done! I have included your comment at the end of this answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 17):

Add **`RUN apk add zlib-dev jpeg-dev gcc musl-dev`** in the Dockerfile and then add **Pillow** in the requirements.txt

Comment: This worked for me, thanks. I had installed build-base and alpine-sdk already and was only missing jpeg-dev from these dependencies.

Comment: This works for me also. I too missed `jpeg-dev`

Answer (score 0):

The [docs](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html) say "Pillow and PIL cannot co-exist in the same environment. Before installing Pillow, please uninstall PIL." Once that is taken care of, the answer by [Nooras Fatima Ansari above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63722987/3129134) solved the issue for me. Based on which docker image you use, you can check the [pillow docker images](https://github.com/python-pillow/docker-images) for exact dependencies for your docker image.

Answer (score -1):

if you're using docker compose as me just run `docker-compose up --build` after of add the pillow into requirements.txt