# AH01215: ImportError: No module named PIL: - python script unable to recognize PIL when running from apache2 config

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

What did you do?

I have configured in apache httpd.conf - enabling of mod_cgi.so and httpd-vhosts.conf.

In httpd-vhosts have following conifguration. Basically am trying to capture all /images/ pattern, read have that process using a index.py script and return back as image/jpeg content.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin abc.xyz@gmail.com
ServerName www.groc-example.com
ServerAlias groc-example.com
Alias "/images/" "/var/www/images/"
DirectoryIndex index.py
ErrorLog "/private/var/log/apache2/groc-example-images-error_log"
CustomLog "/private/var/log/apache2/groc-access-log" common
<Directory "/var/www/images/">
Options +ExecCGI
Allow from all
Require all granted
ForceType text/html
AddHandler cgi-script .py
```

In the index.py am just trying to start the script by trying to import the image. It doenst work i.e. recognize at all. The same import of PIL works from python2/python3 interface in spyder or pycharm or commandlines.

If I remove PIL import statement, the html works or prints out to browser.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
from PIL import Image

print ""
print "hello world"
print "--"
print ""
```

What did you expect to happen?

python script to recognize PIL but it doesnt recognize. I have uninstalled PIL-SIMD multiple times and reinstalled but it isnt working.
Though I have both python2 and python3, default am using python2 and so is apache CGI interface.

What actually happened?

I capture following error in apache logs.

```
AH01215: from PIL import Image: /var/www/images/index.py
AH01215: ImportError: No module named PIL: /var/www/images/index.py
```

What versions of Pillow and Python are you using?

Python 2.7.12
Pillow-SIMD
Pillow-SIMD (4.0.0.post0)

Please help if this wont resolve, I have to completely move away from python.

Comment: Have you tried this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8863917/importerror-no-module-named-pil

Comment: any reason you're using cgi and not wsgi?

Comment: what is your PYTHONPATH while that script is being executed from apache? Is PIL discoverable?

Comment: I solved it by going with mod_wsgi. Somehow i still see this problem to of PIL import failing in apache CGI execution. with mod_wsgi, this is resolved now.

Comment: Also refer to the codebase @ github.com/vishnuprasadh/imgprocessor. Any suggestions are welcome, thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

All - i have tried the links provided by Dan-Dev & others as well. James, am using this only to resize image and send back and intercept calls for only images. All other requests will go to other Appservers through Apache2.

I just printed a sys.path to get following. I am unable to get anything on PYTHONPATH. Note that even here if i comment out and just output the image from os namespace, it works. Issue happens when i try pillow. I uninstalled /reinstalled both python & pillow-simd but still this issue persist.

I also have tried #!/usr/bin/python option as well which doesnt work. I am on mac 10.5.*

['/private/var/www/images', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python27.zip', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC', '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages']