# Error " Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement PIL" when using pip install

Tags: python, cmd, python-imaging-library, failed-installation

When trying to install PIL I keep getting the error "Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement PIL (from versions: ) No matching distribution found for PIL". I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling PIL as suggested in the post [ImportError: No module named PIL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8863917/importerror-no-module-named-pil) but in this case having PIL previously incorrectly installed isn't the issue.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try installing the package named **Pillow**, it's a PIL Fork. You can use it the same as the PIL package.