# Django does not find Pillow though installed

Tags: python, django, docker, python-imaging-library, alpine-linux

Django struggles to find **Pillow** and I'm not quite sure why.

## Environment

Linux Alpine based Docker image, Django 2.2. Here are the relevant parts of:

#### The Dockerfile

```
RUN apk update \
    && apk add --virtual build-deps gcc python3-dev musl-dev jpeg-dev zlib-dev \
    && apk add --no-cache mariadb-dev mariadb-client

# install dependencies
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install pipenv
RUN pip install mysqlclient
COPY ./Pipfile /usr/src/cms/Pipfile
RUN pipenv install --skip-lock --system --dev
RUN apk del build-deps
```

#### The Pipfile

```
[[source]]
name = "pypi"
url = "https://pypi.org/simple"
verify_ssl = true

[dev-packages]

[packages]
django = "==2.2"
markdown = "==3.1.1"
pillow = "==5.0.0"

[requires]
python_version = "3.6"
```

## The issue

When I run `python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000` from the container, I get the following error:

```
django.core.management.base.SystemCheckError: SystemCheckError: System check identified some issues:

ERRORS:
website.Photo.photo: (fields.E210) Cannot use ImageField because Pillow is not installed.
    HINT: Get Pillow at https://pypi.org/project/Pillow/ or run command "pip install Pillow".
```

which is *weird* because `pip install Pillow` gives me

```
Requirement already satisfied: Pillow in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (5.4.1)
```

## About Pillow's conflict with PIL

While having a look at `/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages`, I noticed that I had both **PIL** and **Pillow**. Is this:

1. the source of a **conflict** ([Pillow's documentation](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html)) is quite specific about the need to uninstall PIL
2. pillow's use of the very name *PIL* to maintain compatibility as suggested in [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8863917/importerror-no-module-named-pil)?

From the facts that i) `pip uninstall PIL` -> `not installed` ii) `print(PIL.PILLOW_VERSION)` -> `5.0.0` in python's shell and that iii) Django uses `from PIL import Image` [source](https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/2.2/_modules/django/db/models/fields/files/#ImageField), I would go for hypotheses 2. So if Pillow is installed in the container, why does not Django find it?

## Current path

```
>>> from PIL import Image
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 58, in <module>
    from . import _imaging as core
ImportError: Error loading shared library libjpeg.so.8: No such file or directory (needed by /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PIL/_imaging.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)
```

I added `jpeg-dev` to the Dockerfile but, somehow, it does not seem to be enough. Still digging. Thanks for any clue

Comment: Any reason you're using Pillow 5.0.0 with Python 3.7?

Comment: From what I read, Django does not support Pillow above 5.0.0 and I started my project with Python 3.7. Oh, just saw that `Python 3.7` -> `Pillow>5.2`

Comment: I just rolled back to `python 3.6`, same issue. I edit the post

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Turns out, `jpeg-dev` (required by the compilation) was not enough to satisfy all dependencies during execution. Adding `libjpeg` solved the issue. Updated **Dockerfile**

```
# install mysqlclient
RUN apk update \
    && apk add --virtual build-deps gcc python3-dev musl-dev jpeg-dev zlib-dev \
    && apk add --no-cache mariadb-dev mariadb-client

# install dependencies
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install pipenv
RUN pip install mysqlclient
RUN apk add libjpeg      -------------> et voila
COPY ./Pipfile /usr/src/cms/Pipfile
RUN pipenv install --skip-lock --system --dev
RUN apk del build-deps
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, as I am using Docker, I had to add
`RUN python -m pip install Pillow`
into my DockerFile, before `RUN pip install -r ./requirements/prod.txt`.
Simply running `python -m pip install Pillow` in the terminal
wouldn't work.