# 'from PIL import Image' causes an error in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-imaging-library

I know that this question has been asked before, but my conditions are different. I have installed pillow (pip install pillow) but 'from PIL import Image' throws the error 'No module named PIL.' This makes absolutely no sense to me as I have installed the proper dependencies.

Comment: What directory did your pillow package install into? And are you using an IDE or jupyter environment that sources packages from that directory?

Comment: Make sure you are inside your virtual environment (if using one). Also, I would try `pip3 install pillow`. Finally, in some packages you may need to `import Image`
instead of import PIL (more info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8863917/importerror-no-module-named-pil))

Comment: @ParalysisByAnalysis I installed it here: /anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages (5.3.0). I'm using atom to program the project.