# How to use a PIL image in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, python-imaging-library, python-3.5

So I'm trying to open an image using PIL, resize it, and put it on a tkinter canvas. I've tried importing TkImage:

```
import TkImage
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'TkImage'

from PIL import TkImage
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name 'TkImage'

from PIL.Image import TkImage
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name 'TkImage'

from PIL.Image import Image
i = Image.TkImage()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: type object 'Image' has no attribute 'TkImage'
```

All these raise exceptions. Could someone please help?

Comment: Please add the error messages/exceptions to your question.

Comment: There is nothing named `TkImage`. Did you read some documentation showing something named `TkImage`? Are you wanting to use `ImageTk`?

Comment: That won't work either @BryanOakley

Comment: What does "won't work" mean? You absolutely can import `ImageTk` from PIL.

Comment: It raises an error if I try to import it alone, too @BryanOakley

Comment: Please show the error. Though, just throwing random characters at an `import` statement isn't the right way to solve the problem. There is plenty of documentation showing how to import PIL and its components.

Comment: Here is the error that raises when I try to import ImageTk: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'ImageTk'`

Comment: Are you sure that PIL has been correctly installed on your system? Try `pip install Pillow` in a shell window (command window on Windows), and see if the (re)installation processes without errors.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ImportError: No module named PIL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8863917/importerror-no-module-named-pil)

Comment: What is your Pillow version? Please [edit] your post to show _all_ relevant info, including the new error messages and the current output of `pip show Pillow`.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing named `TkImage` in PIL. There is something named `ImageTk`, however.

```
from PIL import ImageTk
```