# Why does the application crash when using the KivyMD module?

Tags: python, kivy, buildozer

Used Buildozer. Logs from CatLog:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/m/8/.buildozer/android/app/main.py", line 10, in <module>
File "/home/m/8/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/myapp/kivymd/uix/filemanager.py", line 119, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PIL'
Python for android ended.
```

buildozer.spec:

```
requirments = python3, kivy, kivymd, yandex-geocoder, requests, mapview, geopy
android.permissions = INTERNET, WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, READ_LOGS
```

I tried to add pillow / PIL in the requirements, but then the application is not going to

Comment: Attention: PIL is deprecated, and pillow is the successor.

Comment: checkout this thread, incase it is helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8863917/importerror-no-module-named-pil

Comment: @Chitkaran Singh I read this topic, but I can’t understand how it can help. I have a problem when running .apk

Comment: what modules are you using from PIL

Comment: @Chitkaran Singh nobody, KivyMD depends on PIL

Answer (score 0):

I using pillow in my app and it works

add `pillow` to requirement in spec then make sure that you import from it like

`from PIL import Image`