# Error in script (Pillow already installed but its says that isnt)

Tags: python, pip, python-imaging-library

Guys i have pillow installed but when i run my script its says Pillow Not Found. Can someone help me please? I already uninstalled pillow. Sorry for my english.

[image]

Comment: This questions has been asked before. Check this post:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8863917/importerror-no-module-named-pil

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ImportError: No module named PIL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8863917/importerror-no-module-named-pil)

Comment: @SabuhiKhalili they're not the same issue. The one you linked is about `PIL`, the Python Imaging Library, which is no longer maintained. OP is asking about `Pillow`, a fork of PIL that is its replacement. `import Image` does not work with Pillow.

Comment: @MariosKaramanis see my comment above. They're not the same issue.

Comment: What is your Python version? Do you have multiple Python versions installed? It's possible you installed Pillow in one version, but is running the script using another version.

Answer (score 0):

Try uninstalling Pillow and installing again. It should work and then make sure you have no typo. The answer is mentioned in the link I shared above:

```
from PIL import Image
```