# ImportError: No module named PIL works for 3.7, but not 3.8

Tags: python-3.x, python-imaging-library

I have the Pillow module installed as seen on `pip list`. Which shows `Pillow 7.2.0`.

I have code which works on **python 3.7**.

```
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
```

However, when running the same on **python 3.8** get the error message.

```
Exception has occurred: ModuleNotFoundError
No module named 'PIL'
```

I note there is supposed to be a working solution here:
[stack link with potential solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8863917/importerror-no-module-named-pil)

2 solutions are:

1. import Image
2. uninstall Pillow and re-install

However, the above suggestions do not work.

How do i get Image and ImageTK working (on version 3.8) please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could start a virtual environment `venv` or `virtualenv` with clean python3.8 and install modules there or try with:

```
python-3.8 -m pip install Pillow
```

or

```
python3.8 -m pip install Pillow
```

**Edit:**
In the end it worked with:

```
py -3.8 -m pip install Pillow
```

Hope this was useful ;)

Comment: 'python-3.8' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.  both of the above methods fail (not recognised).

Comment: How do you call python 3.8 on your terminal? Try `py -3.8 -m pip install Pillow`

Comment: this works. [solved].  please amend so that it can be upvoted.

Comment: Done amending ;)