# How to fix problem of "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PIL'"?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, python-tesseract

I tried with the solution given in 'stackoverflow', but not resolved.

I am trying to extract text from images with the help of **pytesseract** module from python.

The following are the steps I followed:

code:

```
py -m pip install --user virtualenv
py -m venv tessa #creating virtual environment
c:\Users\folder\tessa\Scripts>activate #activated virtual environment
(tessa) c:\Users\folder>jupyter notebook #initiated jupyter IDE
pip install opencv-python
pip install pytesseract
import pytesseract
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\\Users\\folder\\subfolder\\Local\\Programs\\Tesseract-OCR\\tesseract.exe'
```

Now problem start as shown in the image uploaded here in.

[image: error screen shot]

Also showing error 'ModuleNotFoundError : No module named "Image"'

I am not able to fix this issue. Can anybody help on this error, to fix it?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: did you try this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8863917/importerror-no-module-named-pil

Answer (score 2):

It is saying that the module named [Pillow(PIL)](https://pypi.org/project/Pillow/) is missing.
You can install it using pip. Enter the following in Command Line.

```
pip install Pillow
```

Answer (score 0):

You are lacking the module Pillow. To install it you can run the following command in your command line:

```
py -m pip install Pillow
```

Make sure you are doing this when your environment is active (after using the *activate* command), otherwise you will be installing it on your Python globally.

Comment: File "<ipython-input-15-54a638806203>", line 1
    py -m pip install Pillow
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: tried py -m pip install Pillow. Requirement already statisfied: Pillow in c:\users\..path\python\python39\lib\\site-packages (8.0.1)

Comment: pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\\Users\\folder\\subfolder\\Local\\Programs\\Tesseract-OCR\\tesseract.exe'. In this path, subfolder is AppData in my system. Which is hidden one and admin handled access.

Answer (score 0):

Some modules of Python are pre-installed, but no all. You can find modules index [this official index](https://pypi.org/). Then (if you have added pip to your path when you was installing Python), go to your terminal (cmd in Windows) and execute :

```
pip install [module_name]
```

Then don't forget to import it in your code

If you have want to share your projet, mark all modules used in a file named "requirements.txt" [like that](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/). Then the other user just have to execute

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

And modules will installed in the good version.