# PIL Module not found in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, python-imaging-library, python-import

As I try to import PIL as shown below, it shows me an error message (also shown below).

**Code:**

```
from tkinter import *

#import tkinter as tk

from PIL import ImageTk, Image

root = Tk()

root.title('Title here')

root.iconbitmap('images/logo.ico')

root.mainloop()
```

**Error Message:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:/College/Sem4/Human Computer Interaction/Full project/code here/Home.py", line 2, in <module>
    from PIL import ImageTk, Image
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PIL'
```

**Note:**

> - I have Pillow 8.2.0 installed on my system.
> - I tried doing that "pip install image" and "import Image" thing too but it also didn't work either.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ImportError: No module named PIL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8863917/importerror-no-module-named-pil)

Answer (score 0):

open cmd and run those commands:

```
python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip
python3 -m pip install --upgrade Pillow
```

Comment: ok go to cmd and run the command ```python3```, what version it says?

Comment: - When I ran command as  "python3 -m pip insta..." it says: "Python was not found; run without arguments to install from the Microsoft Store, or disable this shortcut from Settings > Manage App Execution Aliases." so, I ran command as "python -m pip insta..." And it says as: 
It says "Requirement already satisfied: Pillow in c:\users\ng\anaconda3\lib\site-packages" and gives version number I have on my system of the respective items.

In this case: 
pip: (21.1)
Pillow: (8.2.0)

Comment: When I typed python3, it took me to Microsoft store and When I type python --version, it shows: Python 3.8.5

Comment: Visual Studio Code

Comment: I just installed Python 3.9 from MS Store

Comment: can you try run the same code using cmd with the command ```python3 code.py```

Comment: ok write ```python -m pip install --upgrade pip``` and then run this command ```python -m pip install Pillow```

Comment: Same error as before: 

D:\College\Sem4\Human Computer Interaction\Full project\code here>python3 Home.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\College\Sem4\Human Computer Interaction\Full project\code here\Home.py", line 3, in <module>
    from PIL import ImageTk, Image
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PIL'

Comment: if that dosent work, do the first commands i gave you using ```python3 ...``` and it suppose to work

Comment: DAMN!! It works now.. Thanks man... But I am facing another issue, when I try to run it with python3 Home.py it runs, but when I try to run it with "run button" on top-right corner of VS Code, it shows as error as before... "PIL Module not found" error. Is that something you can help me with too ??

Comment: you need to reconfigure the python env in visual studio code, adding a link: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments , good luck!