# Django ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PIL'

Tags: python, django, python-imaging-library

I looked at a lot of SO posts for this error and none of the answers address or resolve the error. Here is the pipfile:

```
    [[source]]
url = "https://pypi.org/simple"
verify_ssl = true
name = "pypi"

[packages]
django = "*"
boto3 = "*"
psycopg2 = "*"
pillow = "*"
django-storages = "*"
django-crispy-forms = "*"
django-s3-storage = "*"
zappa-django-utils = "*"
psycopg2-binary = "==2.8.6"
django-environ = "*"
django-mptt = "*"
djangorestframework = "*"
mortgage = "*"
stripe = "*"
django-phonenumber-field = "*"
phonenumbers = "*"
django-mathfilters = "*"
image = "*"

[dev-packages]
mock = "*"
model-mommy = "*"
django-debug-toolbar = "*"

[requires]
python_version = "3.8"
```

As you can see, I have both the pillow and image packages installed. But, when I run `py manage.py shell`, I get this error:

```
import PIL
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PIL'
```

In my `user_profile app`, I have the following:

```
import PIL
from PIL import Image
...
```

I tried uninstalling different PIL-related packages, I could run `py manage.py shell` without running into the `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PIL'`.  However, once deployed using `AWS lambda`, I ran  into another error:

```
[ERROR] ImportError: cannot import name '_imaging' from 'PIL' (/var/task/PIL/__init__.py)
...
File "/var/task/comments/models.py", line 5, in <module>
  from user_profile.models import UserProfile
File "/var/task/user_profile/models.py", line 13, in <module>
  from PIL import Image
File "/var/task/PIL/Image.py", line 114, in <module>
  from . import _imaging as core
```

So, I went back and installed pillow (`pipenv install pillow`) which shows up in my Pipfile as `pillow = "*"`. Once again deployed using AWS Lambda, and once again the same error message as above (`from . import _imaging as core`)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ImportError: No module named PIL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8863917/importerror-no-module-named-pil)

Comment: Looks like you using different interpreters to run Django server and interactive shell via command line (something alternative installations like pyenv or venv?)

Comment: @bdbd, the post you are referring to is helpful and I did come across it prior to posting the question.  Unfortunately, it did not work for me.  I decided to uninstall all the PIL-related packages (pillow and image) and reinstall to see if that does it.  When I unistalled all and reinstalled image package, it threw another exception. Then, I unistalled image too (```pipenv uninstall image```) and now I have no PIL related package, yet it may be working (as I am dealing with another unrelated issue). When I have a definitive answer, I'll answer my own post

Answer (score 1):

The problem I ran into was due to the fact that Pillow no longer supports `import _imaging`:

```
Warning: 
Pillow >= 2.1.0 no longer supports import _imaging. Please use from PIL.Image import core as _imaging instead.
```

To resolve the problem, you'd need to add

```
from PIL.Image import core as _imaging
```

below `from PIL import Image` in your code.