# Python Pillow (or PIL) not working despite PIP installation

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I am following the documentation: https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

I successfully installed Pillow with pip. However, when I try to import the `Image` function I can:

a) Only import it from PIL
b) Only get an error that there is no module `PIL`
c) Get an error that there is no module `Pillow`

Here's the message (the same thing happens when I try it with Pillow instead of PIL):

```
from PIL import Image
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PIL'
```

And here's proof that I have installed it with pip:

```
Requirement already satisfied: Pillow in c:\python310\lib\site-packages (8.4.0)
```

I read on Stackoverflow that PIL is no longer maintained. However, no question answered my problem:
[ImportError: No module named PIL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8863917/importerror-no-module-named-pil)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have probably installed Pillow in a different Python installation from the one you are using. `pip` and `python` are linked to each other. Let's establish what commands you are using first.

---

**Q1 - What command do you use to run Python scripts?**

What command do you use when you start Python scripts? Or, if you use a graphical IDE, e.g. **VS Code**, **JetBeans**, **IDLE**, what command does it use to start Python?

Likely answers:

- python
- python-2.7
- python3

So, if the answer is `python3`, then in the remainder of the answer `YOURPYTHON` will be `python3`.

---

**Q2 - What command do you use to install Python packages?**

What command do you use to install Python packages?

Likely answers:

- pip
- pip-2.7
- pip3

So, if the answer is `pip3`, then in the remainder of the answer `YOURPIP` will be `pip3`.

---

You have installed with `pip` into your Python 310 installation, you can see that in your *"Requirements satisfied"* message, or by running:

```
YOURPIP -V                # quick version check
YOURPIP show pillow       # more detail as to location
YOURPIP debug             # lots of detail about how pip is set up
```

Now the question is which Python are you using? And where is it looking?

```
YOURPYTHON -V                                            # quick version check
YOURPYTHON -c "import sys; print(sys.executable)"        # where is my Python interpreter?
YOURPYTHON -c "import sys; print('\n'.join(sys.path))"   # where does it look for packages?
```

---

In general, if you use `python`, you should probably use `pip`. But if you use `python3`, you should probably use `pip3` to ensure that you are installing into the same place that your interpreter is looking.

You can get information about what is actually running when you type a command like this:

```
which python    # works on macOS, Linux and Windows
type python     # works on macOS and Linux and is preferable
```

Comment: I am using Python 3.10.0 and pip 21.3.1
When I tried python3 -V, Python was not found

Comment: SOLUTION: I uninstalled a previous Python-Installation that I still had and selected a new interpreter in VSCODE (Python 3.10). It seems to be working now

Answer (score 1):

Run `pip install image --user` and then it should work.

Comment: Didn't work - Permission error

Comment: You should try with user permissions, adding `--user` to the command. I've added it to my answer.

Comment: It worked, but I still can't run it properly.
The installation was successful, but PIL is still not found

Comment: Are you still getting `No module named 'PIL'`?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately. I am still using Python 3.10 and the newest Version of Pillow was installed as previously stated ;(

Comment: WAIT IT WORKED NOW. I was using the wrong Interpreter + the installation of Image helped. Thanks