# Flask Marshmallow module is not being recognized

Tags: python, api, sqlite, flask, marshmallow

**I've tried many Python modules such as marshmallow, flask-marshmallow,..., but none of them it seems to be working. I believe my set up is correct, but it could be wrong. I believe the marshmallow modules are not being recognized although I installed. **

```
import os
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, url_for, flash
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

from flask_marshmallow import Marshmallow
from marshmallow import Schema, fields

app = Flask(__name__)

db = SQLAlchemy()
ma = Marshmallow(app)


app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///database.db'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
db.init_app(app)
conn = sqlite3.connect('database.db')

class Users(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'Users'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String)
    email = db.Column(db.String)
    username = db.Column(db.String)
    
    def __init__(self,id,name,email,username):
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
        self.email = email
        self.username = username

class UsersSchema(ma.SQLAlchemyAutoSchema):
    id = fields.Integer()
    username = fields.String(required=True)
    email = fields.String(required=True)
    password = fields.String(required=True)
        
user_schema = UsersSchema()
```

Comment: Have a look here... https://stackoverflow.com/a/69822500/2836621

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.