# no module named <library_name>

Tags: python, macos, python-import, modulenotfounderror, installation-package

I am having error importing modules in my jupyter notebook when running it on a mac machine after successfully installing them using:

```
!pip install <library name>.
```

I try it on several modules and error persists.

for example, when running this code

```
!pip install pyenchant
```

I get this:

> Requirement already satisfied: pyenchant in
> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages
> (3.2.2)

when running :

```
import enchant
```

I am getting an error message:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyspellchecker'

then try to run this (as I read this could help)

```
!python -m pip install -U pyenchant
```

and get that:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python: No module named pip
```

I think it has something to do with python path and bash_profile but I do not have an intuition for it.

I do not know if it is helpful/relevant, but  I have Pycharm, python, Visual Studio Code and anconda installed on my machine. I am doubting that the problem comes from misalignment between the common configuration files of these programs.

can you please help?

I realize that many has encounter similar issue but their solutions did not help me.

p.s. the issue disappear when I use conda install , but I would like to use pip as it give me access to larger library options.

Comment: I can't explain it much more clearly than here... https://stackoverflow.com/a/69822500/2836621

Comment: this didn't help. i have this (Python 3 (ipykernel)) in my jupyter notebook.