# No model PIL is found

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

`pip install Pillow`

Requirement already satisfied: Pillow in e:\finalproject\fyp\lib\site-packages (9.0.1)

BUT still get error

---

ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
e:\FinalProject\ImageDetection.ipynb Cell 9' in <cell line: 4>()

````
    3 from object_detection.utils import label_map_util

----> 4 from object_detection.utils import visualization_utils as viz_utils

    5 from object_detection.builders import model_builder
    6 from object_detection.utils import config_util```

File e:\FinalProject\fyp\lib\site-packages\object_detection-0.1-py3.10.egg\object_detection\utils\visualization_utils.py:29, in <module>
   ```27 import collections
   28 # Set headless-friendly backend.

---> 29 import matplotlib; matplotlib.use('Agg')  # pylint: disable=multiple-statements

   30 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  # pylint: disable=g-import-not-at-top
   31 import numpy as np```

File e:\FinalProject\fyp\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py:109, in <module>
```  105 from packaging.version import parse as parse_version
  107 # cbook must import matplotlib only within function
  108 # definitions, so it is safe to import from it here.

--> 109 from . import _api, _version, cbook, docstring, rcsetup

  110 from matplotlib.cbook import MatplotlibDeprecationWarning, sanitize_sequence
  111 from matplotlib.cbook import mplDeprecation  # deprecated```

File e:\FinalProject\fyp\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\rcsetup.py:27, in <module>
 ```  25 from matplotlib import _api, cbook
   26 from matplotlib.cbook import ls_mapper

---> 27 from matplotlib.colors import Colormap, is_color_like

   28 from matplotlib.fontconfig_pattern import parse_fontconfig_pattern
   29 from matplotlib._enums import JoinStyle, CapStyle```

File e:\FinalProject\fyp\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\colors.py:51, in <module>

  ``` 49 from numbers import Number
   50 import re

---> 51 from PIL import Image

   52 from PIL.PngImagePlugin import PngInfo
   54 import matplotlib as mpl```

**ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PIL'**
````

Comment: Just for clarification, Do you have two folders in e:\  as FinalProject and finalproject? If not, can you edit the error lines so that they are exactly same as what you get in your system.

Comment: Have a read here... https://stackoverflow.com/a/69822500/2836621