# Python Tkinter music player

Tags: python, tkinter, module

So I am doing a school project but wanted to make it more advanced than required. I have been watching and looking at scripts but dont get the "import example" and "from PIL import ImageTk, Image". Specifically it says:
*line 6, in 
from PIL import ImageTk, Image ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PIL'*
It isn't the only module I have that is in the code.How can I make it work???
[**image**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SP9Cf.png)

Comment: Do you not know how to install modules? What happened when you Googled those modules or how to install modules in general? It's not clear why you're asking on here for help.

Comment: Maybe this answers your question: [ImportError: No module named PIL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8863917/importerror-no-module-named-pil). Did you search on Google _and_ Stack Overflow, and still not find the information you need? That's highly unlikely. To install something, run `python3 -m pip install <module-name>`, replacing `<module-name>` with the name of the module you want to install. Also, please don't post code as images, because it's not searchable and the visually impaired cannot see it at all. See [ask] for more information on asking good questions.

Answer (score 0):

In console using:

python3 -m pip install Pillow

or

python -m pip install Pillow

or

pip3 install Pillow

or

pip install Pillow