# I can't import PIL, with PIL/Pillow package installed

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I installed pillow with `pip install pillow` and it worked. But when importing, it tells me that it cannot find the module.

example : [image: screen_code]

I am on Windows 10 and python 3.9.9

Comment: What if you try to install with `py -m pip install pillow`?

Comment: Does anything in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8863917/importerror-no-module-named-pil answer your question? When you used `pip install pillow`, what messages did you see? When you do `pip list`, do you see the package? Can you make the code work if you run it from the command line? What IDE are you using in that screenshot, and where is it looking for Python? How do you know?

Comment: From the screenshot it looks like you're using some IDE, so it's possible, even likely, that the IDE doesn't know about you installing the PIL. Consult the part of the IDE's documentation about installing modules.