# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PIL' after installing Pillow

Tags: python, tkinter, python-imaging-library

About a week ago, I had this code running on a different machine but currently I am getting a 'ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PIL'' error even though I installed pillow using the command pip install Pillow in the correct directory.

I know this question has been asked a few times but the solutions from them have not worked for me, I have tried a few things...

I am importing pillow using the line

```
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
```

Just trying import Image does not work.

I tried uninstalling pillow where I get the command

```
Found existing installation: Pillow 9.1.0
Uninstalling Pillow-9.1.0:
  Would remove:
    c:\python39\lib\site-packages\pil\*
    c:\python39\lib\site-packages\pillow-9.1.0.dist-info\*
Proceed (Y/n)?
```

EDIT:: When running python --version and pip --version I get this.

```
PS C:\Users\Justin\Desktop\pi\pi-3b+> python --version
Python 3.9.4
PS C:\Users\Justin\Desktop\pi\pi-3b+> pip --version
pip 22.0.4 from C:\Users\Justin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pip (python 3.9)
```

EDIT2:: Also, when running pip install Pillow, this is the result

```
PS C:\Users\Justin\desktop\pi\pi-3b+> pip install Pillow
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ip (c:\python39\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution - (c:\python39\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ip (c:\python39\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution - (c:\python39\lib\site-packages)
Collecting Pillow
  Using cached Pillow-9.1.0-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl (3.3 MB)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ip (c:\python39\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution - (c:\python39\lib\site-packages)
Installing collected packages: Pillow
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ip (c:\python39\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution - (c:\python39\lib\site-packages)
Successfully installed Pillow-9.1.0
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ip (c:\python39\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution - (c:\python39\lib\site-packages)
PS C:\Users\Justin\desktop\pi\pi-3b+>
```

Comment: Usually this is caused by installing the module for a different version of python than you're actually using.  How are you running the code?  Are you running it with `python myscript.py` on the command line, or using an IDE, or some other way?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ImportError: No module named PIL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8863917/importerror-no-module-named-pil)

Comment: @JohnGordon I am running it with python myscript.py yes

Comment: Show us the output of these two commands: `python --version` and `pip --version`

Comment: I just added it to the answer!

Comment: @JohnGordon I also added some more information

Comment: Can you also show the output of this code `import sys; print(sys.path)`

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
import sys
print(sys.executable)
```

to see if the Python you are using is the same one `pip` installed Pillow into.

Comment: It returns miniconda3\python.exe

Comment: Could the location of the install be going to the wrong location possible?

Answer (score 0):

This is a common issue as PIL deprecates. Your question has been asked before and you can find numerous answers here:

[ImportError: No module named PIL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8863917/importerror-no-module-named-pil)