# moduleerror pil not found

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, pyinstaller

when i run my program in python it works but when i use pyinstaller it doesnt work. my app (login.py) imports another file (app.py) which imports PIL
even though i use hidden import to import PIL, i get this when i launch the exe

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "login.py", line 5, in 
> from app import App
> File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 495, in exec_module
> File "app.py", line 2, in 
> from PIL import Image, ImageTk
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PIL'

can anyone please help

Comment: Please follow the debug process as suggested [by this GitHub issue](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/5856) and see which additional hidden modules are needed to be specified.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `import Image` or `from PIL import Image` instead of `import PIL`, as you can check in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8863917/importerror-no-module-named-pil).