# How to resolve No module named 'PIL' error message

Tags: python, module, python-imaging-library, python-import, python-module

I acknowledge that this issue is common and widely reported. However, all solutions listed did not resolve the current issue I am facing.

I have downloaded Pillow using pip. I am using python, not python3 or any other types.
When importing PIL I keep getting modulenotfound errors.

```
import PIL

PIL.__version__
```

Comment: You can find the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8863917/importerror-no-module-named-pil

Comment: *Pillow and PIL cannot co-exist in the same environment. Before installing Pillow, please uninstall PIL.* ; https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/installation.html